# How can I enable debug output?

Tags: julia

I tried printing something to the debug log, but I see no output:

```
julia> @debug "foo"
```

How can I enable debug output?

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`JULIA_DEBUG`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/#Environment-variables-1) environment variable to set debug output.

Set the value to the name of the module for which you want to enable debug logging:

```
julia> ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = Base
```

For the case of `@debug` calls in the REPL, set the module to `Main`:

```
julia> ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = Main
Main

julia> @debug "foo"
┌ Debug: foo
└ @ Main REPL[6]:1
```

The special `all` value will enable debug logging for all modules:

```
julia> ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "all"
```

If want to enable debugging during startup, you can set it through the shell:

```
$ JULIA_DEBUG=all julia
```

Comment: This worked. `all` is not great, just a ton of messages. Use the module name of the test environment you are in, ie the name if you `] activate .`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't work for me, so I did this which changes the global message filter level:

```
using Logging
disable_logging(Logging.Debug) # disable debug, info only
disable_logging(Logging.Debug-2000) # enable debug
```

see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/#Logging.disable_logging